# How to go from 1/6 to 16 2/3

Tags: fractions

A VCR is programmed to record a TV show that lasts for a half hour. If the cassette tape used can accommodate 180 minutes of programming, what percent of the tape is used for this recording?

I did 30/180, reduced to 1/6.

I know the answer is 16 2/3% because I have a key.

How did they turn 1/6 into 16 2/3?

Comment: $1/6=100\%/6=\ldots ?$

Comment: The definition of percentage is that it is the fraction multiplied by 100.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{6}\times 100\%=16\frac 23\%$